# Broken TLS connection from an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tls1.2

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that makes call to an external service that support only TLS1.2 protocol.

When the code makes the call I get this error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException  HResult=0x80131500 Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

It seems that my side (the client one) does not support TLS1.2.

My question are:

1. How can I enable TLS1.2 in a .NET 4.7 application?
2. Is it something that I can force in the code?
3. Consider that the app will be deployed on an Azure APP SERVICE, so I cannot manage IIS settings machine registry stuff.

Thanks,
\sergio

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in code level with below line before calling `web service`

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ;
```

If you are not sure of the protocol you can use below

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me.
I've tried to add the line 

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 `


both before calling the web service, and in the Global.asax Application_Start method, but the result is the same "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: To adds more, the code calling the external web service works fine wheter I run it from my win10 laptop, while it fails when run from a Windows Server 2012 r2.
Clearly Win10 has a different TLS1.2 support compared to the WindowsServer 2012R2 one.
Maybe I have to add something to the WindowsServer 2012R2 to support TLS12?

Comment: check [This](https://support.site24x7.com/portal/en/kb/articles/how-to-check-if-tls-1-2-is-enabled)